# Why am i getting Android Volley ClientError when using Mobile Internet

Tags: android, android-volley

Below is my source code:

```
public void Login() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  getSharedPreferences("Sessions", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedPreferences.edit();
        EditText EmailAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);

            EditText txtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);
            final String Email = EmailAddress.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Password = txtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            Globals globals = new Globals();
            final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Please wait ...", "Validating User", true);
            ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            RequestQueue queue;

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.jobspot.co.ke/Employee/LoginFuncx",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            if(Html.fromHtml(response).toString().trim().equals("True"))
                            {
                                SharedPreferences  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySessions", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                                try {
                                    String myJsonResponce = GlobalRecordCheck("wgm_employeeinfo",Email,"EmailAddress");
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myJsonResponce);
                                    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                                    JSONObject object = result.getJSONObject(result.length()-1);
                                    String EmployeeNo = object.getString("EmployeeNo");
                                    String EmployeeName = object.getString("FirstName")+" "+object.getString("OtherNames");
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                                    editor.putString("jobSpotEmployeeNo", EmployeeNo);
                                    editor.putString("jobSpotEmployer", EmployeeName);
                                    editor.commit();

                                    Login.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                                }catch (JSONException e){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Html.fromHtml(response), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An Error xxOccurred " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Password", Password);
                    params.put("Email", Email);
                    return params;
                }
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // do not add anything here
                    return headers;
                }
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json";
                }
            };
            queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
            queue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem was with my device. The Network mode was set to GSM Only. I Changed it to GSM/WCDMA auto and it worked. The Same Problem also occurs with Retrofit Http library. Retrofit returns *Retrofit.Retrofit error*. Hope this helps someone